# How do I put a newline or linebreak in between date and time without putting it in separate variables

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($event_date);
$event_date = date_format($dateTime, "l n-j-Y g:i A");
```

I want to put a newline between l(day of week) and a newline between the Y(Year) and g(Hour) 
Can I do this without putting it in separate variables?

This is to be echoed in html.

Comment: What does "pulling it apart" mean?

Comment: Do you mean a HTML newline, or a "regular" one? Where is this going to be used?

Comment: `$event_date = date_format($dateTime, "l n-j-Y\ng:i A");` or `$event_date = date_format($dateTime, "l n-j-Y<br />g:i A");`

Comment: I edited the question to address your comments.

I have tried:
l<\b\r>n-j-Y<\b\r>g:i A   which starts off a bold tag.
l<br />n-j-Y<br />g:i does nothing.
and l\nn-j-Y\ng:i A does nothing probably because I am echoing in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the date_format into separate pieces

```
$event_date = date_format($dateTime, "l") .
   "<br/>" .
    date_format($dateTime, "n-j-Y") .
    "<br/>" .
    date_format($dateTime, "g:i A");
```

You can do the same with a new line character, just substituting \n for the br tag.

Answer (score -2):

Use /n for a newline character:

```
document.write("\n");
```

However, if this is rendering to HTML, you will want to use the HTML tag for a newline:

```
document.write("<br>");
```

Comment: That's not PHP, it's JavaScript.

Comment: Im sorry, I didnt read the tags on the comment, I was reading it to fast! my mistake!